# Making my React app working with a Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a question and got confused with the articles I found on the internet.
I have a react App which deploys on the development server. I want to create an admin part, where the administrator will be able to push content into the database. React App will get content from a Database and render it.

Also after the development, I want to upload this on hosting so users from the internet can have access to it and use it. I understand how the server works with post\get requests from glitch projects.

Writing on React.Js, server with express.js

So can someone explain to me the following:

1. how the server sends React app? Should I send simple index.html with #root div and the whole website will work?
2. I am a bit confused about how hand-made server and API are different from hostings? How to connect then backend with a hosting?
3. IN VSCode is it possible to make a react App showing from the server of Node.js? - On glitch I can 
   sendfile index.html with simple request and I see the landing page.

So theoretically I should have a possibility to send static file through a server of Node.js/Express.js?

Can you explain these questions to me, please or provide some resources where it explained? Currently I'm watching Youtube and Google but how to connect it with my project I do not get a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pretty much. If you use `create-react-app` to build your React frontend, the build result folder will contain all the static files required (HTML, CSS, JS, images, fonts...). You can then either have your Express app serve it as static data.
2. "Hosting" is a nebulous term... No, you can't upload a Express/Node.js app to some PHP web hotel and expect it to work. You'll need an application-hosting centered provider/PaaS such as Heroku.
3. When developing a react + backend app locally, you'd have your backend server running, and the frontend dev server up to serve your frontend and configured to proxy all API requests to the backend server [(like this, via the Create-React-App docs)](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply.
1 - ok, understand.

2 - so if I buy a domain and deploy it to a hosting. How to make React application work with Admin panel and fetching data from a database? 

3 - Again - I wrote API for local Node server, then how to make it work on the internet and domain? 
I will read the docs you mentioned, but just asking in advance

UPD: I see it's about proxy in React - I saw that and used event. It is for fetching data from a server, right? But If I have a database, should I provide data then to a server and then from server to an app ?

Comment: 2) An "admin panel" style hosting probably can't host your Node.js app. You will likely need shell access, or a PaaS. 3) Yes, database<->server<->frontend is the usual cycle, unless you're using e.g. Firebase for your database.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, thank you very much for the explanation provided.